# Raspberry Pi 3 - Keyboard & Mouse Not Getting Power

Tags: pi-3, keyboard, mouse

I turned on the Pi for the first time, it is showing red light but the keyboard and mouse connected are not showing any light like they normally do. I didn't inserted the SD card, is that a requirement for keyboard or mouse to work?

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 charger to power up Pi, it's adapter meets the requirement, i.e, 5V and 2A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't inserted the SD card, is that a requirement for keyboard or mouse to work?

Yes. The Pi requires a correctly formatted SD card in order to do anything.  Otherwise, it is like removing the hard drive from your computer only worse, because the Pi has no BIOS/UEFI, and the CPU is bootstrapped by the GPU using firmware loaded from the SD card.

Comment: Ok so just to test that devices are working, I will insert SD card with NOOBS but without connecting the monitor, now will the keyboard and mouse get power?

Comment: Presuming the SD card is formatted properly.  The green ACT light should flicker quickly and irregularly for a number of seconds (probably at least 5, but it may be over a minute).  If it never comes on, comes on and stays on, or begins repeatedly flashing in a regular, steady pattern, the card is invalid.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria IIRC you will need a monitor yo setup noobs the first time.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yeah but to setup noobs, I first need to make sure that keyboard and mouse are working

Comment: Beware that pulling the plug arbitrarily risks filesystem corruption, meaning you should not do this without a monitor repeatedly and expect it to keep working.